# Laravel: how to create site with few subdomains?

Tags: php, laravel, web

I am going to do a big project and I need your suggestions. What to use for site with subdomains? For example: domain.com, admin.domain.com, blog.domain.com and etc.

I found a multiple Laravel sites package https://github.com/appstract/laravel-multisite/?utm_source=learninglaravel.net but I just create route groups where I declare domain and subdomains urls and then creating routes for each domain/subdomain.

So, maybe I need to use this package or my idea is great? Also, you can offer me something.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't Laravel support matching routes on subdomains [out of the box](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)? Then it's just a matter of configuring nginx or whatever to all point to the same app.

Comment: So I do like this. Make route groups with domain/subdomain name and inside them writting routes for site. I just asked because maybe this package is better?

Comment: I'm really not sure what that package actually does. IMO, less is more. If you don't need it, don't use it.